# phonegap plugins and different platform files?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I found the phonegap wiki and plugins github site.  I am new to phonegap and wanting to use the childbrowser plugin.  I am historically a web developer and looking to use phonegap build online.  What files are needed on my web site so that when i deploy to multiple devices all will be good.
I am a bit confused. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser

1)  Why are the plugins by device/platform? (it was my understanding that i would put some files on my website project and when pg build took it, it would build for all platforms.  So why do are the plugins sorted by platform?

2) I will be on windows platform, testing on android.  Do you recommend vs.net or eclipse for building the project?

ty

Answer (score 0):

well AFAIU understand you want to build a "website" using phonegap, at least that is why I understood when you use the word "website".

On that case Phonegap is an API and help use access the device capabilities like camera, file system, etc. However Phonegap (Cordova) is intended to build hybrid apps, this means that although you can leverage of all your HTML, CSS and JS skills the idea is to ease the mobile app development process, so it is not intended to develop a normal "website" to access the device hardware. You will need to deploy the project on an actual device instead of expecting someone visit your website and works as a normal app.

1) There are plugins for each platform as Phonegap (Cordova) alleviate us from programming for each platform specifically, it take our code and take the proper platform code to achieve what we want (in brief).

It is worth to take a look to this documentation and understand the CLI (command line interface) to install the plugins.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

2) You can actually use what it best fit your needs. Eclipse is more focused on android development so probably it is worth to try it.

Well, don´t confuse Phonegap or Cordova with Phonegap build, the latest is a service offered by Phonegap to build your projects on the cloud, however you can build your project without PGB using the command line interface.

### Resources to start developing with Phonegap

I strongly recommend reading some good books or watching some tutorials before jumping into the magic of Phonegap, also read the documentation. Even if it take you 3 4 days to do so that will save you tons of hours later during development.

I recommend "Lynda Up and Running with PhoneGap" 2 hours video tutorial. All will be cleared by watching the tutorial.
http://www.lynda.com/HTML-tutorials/Up-Running-PhoneGap/99541-2.html

Book: Phonegap Essentials by John M. Wargo, although it was written on the early phonegap versions is still nice and neat.